# YouTube Data API V3 - Last youtube video randomly disapears from research

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

I'm working on an application which has to get the last youtube video published on a YouTube channel. To find it, I am using request to this address:

```
'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=1&key=' + key + '&channelId=' + myChannelId;
```

My application is not working well, it notifies me the two newest videos, one after the other, again and again. I've tried to refresh the result several times, after setting maxResults to 50, and sometimes the real last video disapears of the research, so the last video found is not the right.

Is youtube data API not working as expected? Or am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
As you can see, a simple refresh make a roll between the two newest videos : https://youtu.be/OqDCeRFYq14

Comment: Can you share your `channelId`? In my tests with known channels I'm receiving the correct results.

Comment: "UCRJIg6em1e_Sw8VJ6SpN5yg", last video can randomly be "[REINHART]  -  ..." or "[D.VA] - MECHA ACTIVATED - ..." when the real last published video is "[D.VA] - MECHA ACTIVATED - ...". I've already got this issue on another channel months ago.

Comment: Only got the wrong one during last 10 minutes.

Comment: @Nucktrooper:  I'm getting the correct results for your channel id, however, I experience the same problem as you with other channels (not random, but not seeing the most recent).I have been testing with the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list), so that should eliminate your application as being the problem.

Comment: As you can see, a simple refresh make a roll between the two newest videos : https://youtu.be/OqDCeRFYq14

Comment: Not random indeed. With my channel number of results displayed can be 176 or 177. Sometimes the last video disapears, so it's the one published just before which is found.

Comment: Youtube does not use the api that we used for getting data, Apis sending you data is based on many things like server load, how many times you call the app randomly, I think, you have refreshed page randomly many times one by one and thats why sometimes it gives you correct result and sometimes not, I have faced this problem many times.

Comment: Same thing happened when it's my application which contact the API, but it's easier to show it in browser. My application automatically ask for last video every 5 minuts.